# wordpress as a decision tree

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, decision-tree

I'm not sure if it's called a decision tree, but I was looking to create a website that contains a question and can be answered by clicking a yes or no button.

I wanted to do this in Wordpress but I haven't come across any examples.  I figure since each post has a unique id, this should be possible but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Can someone offer some ideas on this or show a template that might do something

Example of what I'd like to do:
A user goes to my website and the main page asks, "Did you eat today?"  The user has the option to click on a yes or no button.  If user clicks yes, the user get certain information.  If user clicks no, then the user is directed to completely different information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the most simple level, all you need to do is create each page as a Page (not a Post) and create the question pages with links to answer pages (with the answer Yes or No as the link text). Then style the links to look like buttons.

Comment: thanks @Paul. That makes sense.  Have you ever come across a site that does this?  Just to see how it's been done?

Answer (score 0):

Try these WordPress plugins:

1. **Sidecar Decision Tree** -
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/sidecar-decision-tree/
2. **Zingtree** - https://wordpress.org/plugins/zingtree/